# Passing null when can't fetch an enum value?

Tags: java, android, enums, null

I'm currently working on an Android app (question is not necessarily Android specific) that has a lot of custom infrastructure built in. We have to, in some cases, make an expensive and very time-sensitive server call (to an API we don't own) from one part of the architecture, then pass the result to the UI. In some cases, we skip making the server call because it's unnecessary, but we still need to talk to the UI and basically say "we didn't make the server call, so make it yourself if you end up needing it."

The result of the server call is an enum defined as basically NOT_AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE_IN_ONE_CASE, and AVAILABLE_IN_ALL_CASES. When we don't make the server call, we don't want to pass NOT_AVAILABLE, because we don't know that (didn't check) and want the UI to figure it out on their own if necessary. Is passing null when we haven't made the check a code smell, or does it sound appropriate here?

The other approach I can think of is defining our own enum compositionally that basically says DID_NOT_CHECK, NOT_AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE_IN_ONE_CASE, AVAILABLE_IN_ALL_CASES, but since this is all private that seems like overkill. I tend to overengineer so I'm trying to follow my instincts/figure out if there's a rule of thumb.

Comment: As a rule, I prefer to not pass `null` around and instead use a special value like an empty List or a special valued enum as you suggest.  However as you say if it's all internal you can probably use `null` and just fix it later if it starts causing problems.

Comment: I don't think it is over kill to provide your own Enum, I would use a factory method that can return the correct enum based on the expensive call's result.  You are providing reducing coupling a little by introducing your own type, and reducing the number of wrong values that can be returned, reducing your testing space.  It's all too easy for us to fall into the expedient trap of returning null.  Go with your own type... "its the only way to be sure" :)

Answer (score 0):

## `Optional`

The [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) type was invented to represent the case where a null would be considered a valid value to be returned from a method. The `Optional` object can contain nothing, being empty, effectively a `null`. Or the `Optional` can contain an object as its contents.

➥ Enums work with `Optional`.

Take for example the `java.time.Month` enum, with twelve enum objects defined, one for each month.

```
Optional<Month> month = Optional.of( Month.MARCH );
```

In your case:

```java
public enum Availability
{
    NOT_AVAILABLE, AVAILABLE_IN_ONE_CASE, AVAILABLE_IN_ALL_CASES;
}
```

And a method that internally decides whether or not to make the call to the server.

```java
public Optional < Availability > determineAvailability ( )
{
    boolean makeTheCallToServer = true;  // Or whatever.
    if ( makeTheCallToServer )
    {
        Availability availability = Availability.AVAILABLE_IN_ALL_CASES; // Or whatever.
        return Optional.of( availability );
    } else
    {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Use that method.

```java
Optional < Availability > availabilityOptional = whatever.determineAvailability();
System.out.println( "availabilityOptional = " + availabilityOptional );
```

> availabilityOptional = Optional[AVAILABLE_IN_ALL_CASES]

Study the several methods on `Optional` to test if it contains a value or is empty, and to optionally return some other value if none is contained.

For example:

```java
if( availabilityOptional.isEmpty() )
{
    String message = "Unknown at this time. Check back later." ;
    …
}
```